# Changing a parent DDL causes error in Child DDL

Tags: c#, asp.net

> Scheduling a Vehicle for Service Design:  A vehicle is chosen from a gridview and the AutoID associated with the vehicle is passed to the service aspx page. At this point, textboxes for the Year, Make and Model are populated based upon the AutoID.

When I select a Category, such as General, the associated SubCategories are loaded into the ddlSubCategory DDL.
At this point, if I change the Category to another value such as Mechanical, the application errors.

The error message is:

> 'ddlSubCategory' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value.

In my code, I issue a ddlSubCategory.Items.Clear() when the ddlCategory_SelectedIndexChanged method is hit. This is an attempt to ensure all the SubCategory items are associated with the selected Category.

I set a breakpoint on the ddlCategory_SelectedIndexChanged method and viewed the values of,  ddlCategory.Items.Count , ddlCategory.SelectedItem.Text, ddlSubCategory.Items.Count, and ddlSubCategory. SelectedItem.Text.  They all display the expected values.  NOTE: I have an ADD Vehicle page with Parent/Child DDL's and that logic works as expected and is the basis for the SERVICE vehicle code.

Below is the associated ASPX, and C# code behind definitions.
Service ASPX Page:

```
<div class="ColumnTxtBoxDDL">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory"  Autopostback="true" BackColor ="#CCCCCC" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCategory_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Label ID="lblMakeForceSelection" CssClass="WarningMessages" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

Service aspx.cs code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Define the variables which will accept the AutoID value which was passed into the Auto variable on the ServiceAuto.aspx page when the SERVICE hyperlink is activated.
    string strID = "";
    int intID = 0;

    // The following line determines whether or not the Auto exists. The AutoID is passed into the query string in the following line
        
    if ((!IsPostBack) && Request.QueryString["Auto"] != null)
    {
        //If the AutoID does exist, then get the Auto's information and populate the form
        strID = Request.QueryString["Auto"].ToString();
        intID = Convert.ToInt32(strID);
        // Create an object of the Vehicles class
        Vehicles TODB = new Vehicles();
        //Fill the "TODB" object with the Auto info based on AutoID by calling the FindOneAuto() method in the Vehicles class and passing the AutoID value (which has been converted from string on the web form into an integer).
        SqlDataReader reader = TODB.FindOneAuto(intID);

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // Fill the text boxes on the ServiceAuto.aspx form.
            txtAutoID.Text = reader["AutoID"].ToString();
            txtYear.Text = reader["Year"].ToString();
            txtMake.Text = reader["Make"].ToString();
            txtModel.Text = reader["Model"].ToString();             
        } // End of While Loop
    } // End of Page_Load

protected void ddlCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Add code here that will populate the SubCategories ddlSubCategory based upon values in the ddlCategory
    if (!ddlCategory.SelectedItem.Text.Contains("Please"))
    {
        // Set ddlSubCategory 'Enabled' Property to True if ddlCategory does not contain "Please..."
        ddlSubCategory.Enabled = true;
        // Clear the Error Message
        lblMakeForceSelection.Text = " ";
        // Set the background color back to default
        ddlSubCategory.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;         
    }       
    else
    {
        ddlSubCategory.Enabled = false;
    }

    // First clear the items in the ddlSubCategory object to ensure they ddlSubCategory object is loaded with items specific to the Category DDL. 
    ddlSubCategory.Items.Clear();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AutoMaintenance"].ConnectionString;       
    String strQuery = "SELECT SubCategoryID, SubCategory FROM SubCategories WHERE Category=@Category";        
    conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    SqlCommand subCategoryComm = new SqlCommand();
    subCategoryComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", ddlCategory.SelectedItem.Text);
    subCategoryComm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    subCategoryComm.CommandText = strQuery;
    subCategoryComm.Connection = conn;

    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            conn.Close();
            conn.Open();            }
            ddlSubCategory.DataSource = subCategoryComm.ExecuteReader();
            ddlSubCategory.DataTextField = "SubCategory";
            ddlSubCategory.DataValueField = "SubCategoryID";
            ddlSubCategory.DataBind();

            if (ddlSubCategory.Items.Count > 1)
            {
                ddlSubCategory.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please Select a SubCategory", "0"));
                ddlSubCategory.Text = " ";
                ddlSubCategory.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                ddlSubCategory.Enabled = true;
            }

            if (ddlSubCategory.Items.Count <= 0)
            {
                lblSubCategoryMessage.Text = "There are no SubCategories within the Selected Category";
            }

            if (!ddlSubCategory.SelectedValue.Contains("Please"))
            {
                calServiceScheduleDate.Enabled = true;
                txtServiceScheduleDate.ReadOnly = false;
            }
            else
            {
                ddlSubCategory.Enabled = false;
                lblSubCategoryMessage.Text = "There are no SubCategories associated with the selected Category. Add new SubCategory via the Database Management page";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
    }
```